# doxygen: nest subpage titles inside section title in treeview

Tags: doxygen

I would like to customise the appearance of the navigation tree column to have subpages' title nested inside the section's title they are referenced in. For instance, this simple example

```
/**
 * @mainpage Mainpage
 * @section section_1 Section 1
 * Description of section 1
 *
 * @section section_2 Section 2
 * Section 2 is composed of the following modules:
 * - @subpage module_1_page
 * - @subpage module_2_page
 */

/**
 * @page module_1_page Module 1
 * Module 1 description
 */

/**
 * @page module_2_page Module 2
 * Module 2 description
 */
```

results in the following output:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is something like this (I manually edited the HTML result):

[image]

I had a look at the page [Customizing the output](https://doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) of the Doxygen documentation, but I was not able to find anything that seems helpful in this case.

Also, I had a look at [grouping](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) as an alternative to pages, but it does not really fit my purposes - I use groups for actual APIs documentation, whereas I'd like to use pages for more "descriptive" documentation.

Is this possible to achieve? For the sake of completeness, I am using doxygen v1.8.13.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is quite old  *December 29, 2016), please upgrade first and check against the current version (1.9.5 ).

Comment: Should it make any difference? Anyway, I tried with version 1.9.5 and got the same result.

Comment: Maybe you should have a `\subsection` instead of a `\page` and replace the `\subpage` by `\ref` to the subsection.

Comment: I thought about that, but a subsection is not really what I would like. The content of each subpage is too long for being a subsection, and most importantly has subpages as well. Subpages are exactly what I need to organise my documentation; I would just like to change their visualisation in the navigation tree, if possible.

Comment: There are a few nestings deeper possible like with `\subsubsection`